# conflict between command line calls (by dev user) and browser requests (apache / www-data)

Tags: php, permissions, apache2, command-line-interface, silverstripe-4

On my development machine I have a public directory to view a test site. Sometimes I change files using command line PHP and sometimes the files are changed by Apache. This leads to endless conflicts (apache can't write because user owns its OR user can't write because www-data owns it).

I have added myself to the www-data group, but I am still getting errors.

What is the best approach here - i.e. who should own the file, what group, and what should the permissions be (e.g. 0777 - obviously not, but you get the idea).

THANK YOU

Comment: If you allow logins as the apache user (by default they don't have a shell configured) then you could run your command line operations as the same user. Note that SilverStripe creates cache files by the user running the process, note the group that the user is in - this could explain why you end up with conflicts. See https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/issues/5550

Comment: Deployer.org solves this by using ACL list (access control lists), then you can say: the user "nicolaas" owns the file, but www-data can r/w the file. My hoster solves this by running apache as the account user for each website.

Answer (score 0):

```
# jump into the project's folder
cd /var/www/www.my-site.com

# exec dev/build as user www-data to avoid conflicts 
# (www-data has no shell configured, so you must define it via -s option)
su www-data -s /bin/bash -c "php vendor/silverstripe/framework/cli-script.php dev/build \"flush=all\""
```